# Fourier Transform of a modulated signal?

Tags: fourier-transform

How do I compute the fourier transform of a signal:

$$Ax(t)\cos(\omega t)  $$

where both $A$ and $\omega$ are constants. I tried using the fact the function was even and using Euler's formula but I ended up with $2$ equations, both of which equal zero.

Comment: Do you know the convolution theorem (for Fourier transforms)?

Comment: Is $x(t)$ even? Unless it is, how can you know that the whole function is even?

Comment: @Fabian the definition of it yes. However, I'm not sure how to apply it in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convolution theorem reads
$$ \sqrt{2\pi} \mathcal{F} ( f g) =\mathcal{F}(f) * \mathcal{F}(g) $$
for any functions $f(t)$, $g(t)$ and where 
$$ (F*G)(\nu) = \int d\mu F(\nu-\mu) G(\mu) = \int d\mu F(\mu) G(\nu-\mu) .$$
Apply this to the functions $$f(t) = x(t)$$ and $$g(t) = A \cos(\omega t).$$

Let us denote the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ by $F(\nu)= X(\nu)$. The Fourier transform of $g(t)$ can be explicitly obtained as
$$G(\nu) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}A}{2}\left[ \delta(\nu-\omega) + \delta(\nu+\omega)\right]\;.$$

Performing the convolution, we obtain that
$$\mathcal{F}[A x(t) \cos(\omega t)](\nu)=\frac{A}{2}[X(\nu-\omega)+X(\nu+\omega)].$$
We see that the carrier frequency $\omega$ shifts the frequencies $\nu$ of the amplitude modulation to $\nu \pm \omega$.